# Problem with parsing Json double-quotation mark

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Gson to convert a json to java object. Here is the Gson

```
{
    "assetClassDetails":[{}],
    "assetClassRequired":null,
    "baseUnitofMeasure":"PMI",
    "bomParent":"Yes",
    "commodityCodeTaric":"84158200",
    "enLanguageKey":"EN",
    "enMaterialLongText":"Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)"",
    "grossWeightInKg":null,
    "height":null,
    "heightLengthWidthUnit":null,
    "length":null,"manufacturerPartNumber":"",
    "materialLongDescription":"Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)"",
    "physicalCategory":"Physical",
    "volume":null,
    "volumeUnit":null,
    "width":null,
    "xxLanguageKey":null,
    "xxMaterialLongText":null
 }
```

Problem is with the attributes enMaterialLongText & materialLongDescription. Inside value they have quotation marks.Gson fails to parse json.
My code is

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
OperationalInfo outout = gson.fromJson(inputJson, OperationalInfo.class);
```

OperationalInfo class is like this:

```
public class OperationalInfo {

private String commodityCodeTaric= null;  //  fETCH FROM db

private String physicalCategory= null; 
private String materialType= null; // ZN01 *
private String productHierarchy= null; // Gnp Hierarchy
private String baseUnitofMeasure= null; // From Database
private String height= null; // Manual enetered
private String length= null; // Manual enetered
private String width= null; // Manual enetered
private String heightLengthWidthUnit= null; // Manual enetered
private String volume= null; // Manual enetered
private String volumeUnit= null; // Manual enetered
private String grossWeightInKg= null; // Manual enetered
private String itemCategoryGroup= null;
private String manufacturerPartNumber= null; // is same as spn
private String bomParent= null;  // yes/No    
private String materialLongDescription= null; // Manual enetered
private String enLanguageKey= null; // EN
private String enMaterialLongText= null; // materialLongDescription
private String xxLanguageKey= null;   //  EN
private String xxMaterialLongText= null;      
private String catalogueGroup = null;
private String pirStatus = null;  // Changed, Add , mark for Delete
private List<AssetClassLedger> assetClassDetails = null;
private Boolean assetClassRequired = null;
...
}
```

I have tried String.replace() on input json to replace double quotation  mark with "\".

**Update:**
Pl refer my following code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String test = "{\"assetClassRequired\":\"\",\"baseUnitofMeasure\":\"PMI\",\"bomParent\":\"Yes\",\"commodityCodeTaric\":\"84158200\",\"enLanguageKey\":\"EN\",\"enMaterialLongText\":\"Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14\\\" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)\\\"\",\"grossWeightInKg\":\"\",\"height\":\"\",\"heightLengthWidthUnit\":\"\",\"length\":\"\",\"manufacturerPartNumber\":\"\",\"materialLongDescription\":\"Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14\\\" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)\\\"\",\"physicalCategory\":\"Physical\",\"volume\":\"\",\"volumeUnit\":\"\",\"width\":\"\",\"xxLanguageKey\":\"\",\"xxMaterialLongText\":\"\"}";
JsonReader reader1 = new JsonReader(new StringReader(test));
reader1.setLenient(true);
OperationalInfo operationalInfo = gson.fromJson(reader1, OperationalInfo.class);
```

Pl see that I have used 3 back-slashes for enMaterialLongText & materialLongDescription for 14 inch. But programmatically how will I know which quotation mark to escape by triple-backslash & which one to single-backslash ?

Comment: It fails to parse it, because it is invalid JSON. Ask the party you get that JSON from to encode it properly.

Comment: @Ivar NodeJs able to parse this malformed with JSON.parse(), problem with java.

Comment: [No, it doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/0ntaehqk/). It is invalid JSON. (Run it through [a validator](https://jsonlint.com/) yourself.)

Comment: @Ivar agreed that it is not a valid json, but I have to turn it into valid json & then parse. My game-plan is this split the input on comma which delimits a key-value pair. But there are also comma inside value. So use a regex for comma not followed by double quotation - (,)[\\s]*([^\"]) & replace it with string literal _COMMA_. Now I need a regex which will take care of nested quote. Once json gets parsed in java object I can change the property to have have nested quote.

Comment: The problem is, that there is simply no way to guarantee that you are correctly fixing the JSON. You will need to escape the backslashes, but you cannot know which one are part of the value and which one are not. [Here is a simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/xowdagem/). There are two valid JSON's, both with backslashes escaped. The first one is probably the one you looking for, but the second one _also_ only escaped backslashes (no other changes except some newlines, which are ignored in JSON). They are both equally valid and a program cannot tell which you are looking for.

Comment: The only way to get the correct JSON, is for the producer of this JSON to fix their error and to properly escape the JSON values. (And it probably takes them way less time to fix than it would take you.)

Answer (score 1):

Since your JSON is invalid, I would contact the source of the JSON to get a valid JSON. But if you **really have no other way** to get a valid JSON, you can try to edit the JSON beforehand to make it approximately valid. But since you can't know what the JSON looks like correctly, I strongly advise you not to use this method.

```java
/**
 * This method tries to escape incorrect quotes. To do this, it looks at which character comes
 * after a quote character, because it assumes that a closed quote character is followed by either
 * a ",", ":", or "\n". However, if none of the characters follows, the quotation mark is
 * escaped.
 * <br />
 * Example Input:
 * <pre>
 *   { "hello": "world " test "", "number": 0 }
 * </pre>
 * Example Output:
 * <pre>
 *   { "hello": "world \" test \"", "number": 0 }
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param json The invalid JSON input
 * @return (Hopefully) correct JSON
 */
private static String tryFixJson(String json) {
  final StringBuilder resp = new StringBuilder();
  final char[] chars = json.toCharArray();
  boolean open = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    final char c = chars[i];
    if (c == '"') {
      if (!open) {
        if (i != 0 && chars[i - 1] != '\\') {
          open = true;
        }
      } else if (i != chars.length - 1) {
        if (chars[i - 1] != '\\') {
          final char n = chars[i + 1];
          if (n != ',' && n != ':' && n != '\n') {
            resp.append('\\');
          } else {
            open = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    resp.append(c);
  }
  return resp.toString();
}
```

Comment: I posted an [answer for a very  similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517135/3832970), I think you would like to take a look.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, it is not only very similar, actually it is same problem & my problem. Thanks for your guidance. Originally I was thinking about Json parsing, later on understood that it is regex problem - fix the JSON & then any json parser will parse it.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you need to escape special characters like `"` and `\`.
Just add a backslash before the special character and you'll be fine:

```json
{
  "enMaterialLongText": "Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14\" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)\""
}
```

Same goes for `materialLongDescription`.

Comment: Not really true. `"` and `\ ` are the only "unsafe" characters to escape in JSON. `{`, `}`, `[`, `]` are not among them.