# How to convert an invalid json into a valid json so that it could be parsed

Tags: java, json, regex

I have an invalid json coming from front end which I have no control. The json is like this:

```
{
    "assetClassDetails":[{}],
    "assetClassRequired":null,
    "baseUnitofMeasure":"PMI",
    "bomParent":"Yes",
    "commodityCodeTaric":"84158200",
    "enLanguageKey":"EN",
    "enMaterialLongText":"Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)"",
    "grossWeightInKg":null,
    "height":null,
    "heightLengthWidthUnit":null,
    "length":null,"manufacturerPartNumber":"",
    "materialLongDescription":"Lenovo Privacy Filter for 14" Notebooks ( L, T and X1 Carbon)"",
    "physicalCategory":"Physical",
    "volume":null,
    "volumeUnit":null,
    "width":null,
    "xxLanguageKey":null,
    "xxMaterialLongText":null
 }
```

Pl. look at enMaterialLongText & materialLongDescription. I have decided to split the whole string on comma character. But here comma is not only key-value pair delimiter, it is also there inside some values. So I used a regex like this:

```
test = test.replaceAll("(,)[\\s]*([^\"])", "_COMMA_ $2");
```

That works. Now I need another regex so that nested quotes can be converted to string such as "*QUOTE*". After Gson has parsed the json into java object, I can convert properties like enMaterialLongText & materialLongDescription to escaped quote mark.

Comment: If your invalid JSON is formatted like that, with each key-value on its own line, you might use `String result = Pattern.compile("(?<=\":\").*(?=\")").matcher(text).replaceAll(x -> x.group().replace("\"", "_QUOTE_") );`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am using java 8, it is Matcher.replaceAll does not take a functional interface till java 9. Can you please suggest me how to modify this for java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If keys and values are not formatted as in the question, arbitrarily, you can't fix the JSON on your end, it should be fixed on the provider's side.

*Assuming* the key-value pairs are on separate lines you may use

```java
StringBuffer fixedJSON = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=\":\").*(?=\")").matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(fixedJSON, m.group().replace("\"", "_QUOTE_"));
}
m.appendTail(fixedJSON);
System.out.println(fixedJSON.toString());
```

The `(?<=\":\").*(?=\")` regex matches values located after `":"` till the last `"` like this:

- `(?<=\":\")` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `":"` immediately to the left of the current location
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?=\")` - a positive lookahead that requires a `"` immediately to the right of the current location.